# Concatenate column values in csv based on grouping condition

Tags: python, csv, concatenation, string-concatenation, text-manipulation

I have a csv that is like the below (Note: values in `Name` column are not limited i.e. not only `ABC` and `DEF`):

```
Name, Type, Text 
ABC, Type A, how
ABC, Type A, are
ABC, Type A, you
ABC, Type B, Your
ABC, Type B, Name?
DEF, Type A, I
DEF, Type A, am
DEF, Type A, good
DEF, Type B, I'm
DEF, Type B, Terminator
... and more
```

I want to create another csv file like below (i.e. Group `Text` column based on `Type` column for every `Name` column):

```
Name, Type, Text
ABC, Type A, how are you
ABC, Type B, Your Name?
DEF, Type A, I am good
DEF, Type B, I'm Terminator
..till the end
```

I am trying to write a python script. My attempt as below:

```
TypeList = ['Type A','Type B']
with open("../doc1.csv", encoding='utf-8', newline='', mode="r") as myfile:
    
    g = csv.reader(myfile)

    with open("../doc2.csv", encoding='utf-8', newline='', mode="w") as myfile:
        h = csv.writer(myfile)
        h.writerow(["Name","Text"])

        for row in g:
            if TypeList[0] in row[1]:    
               Concatenatedtext[0]= Concatenatedtext[0] + ' ' + row[1]
```

Can someone please help me out with this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping csv rows together is a task for the [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function.

`itertools.groupby` accepts a key function that defines matching rows, and emits the key (here, the name and type) and the group (the rows that match) for each match found.

The [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function can be used to create the key function.

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator

# A function that gets the Name and Type values for each row:
# this is used to group the rows together.
key_func = operator.itemgetter(0, 1)

with open('myfile.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skip header row
    next(reader)
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(reader, key=key_func):
        text = ' '.join(cell[2] for cell in group)
        print([key[0], key[1], text])
```

Output:

```
['ABC', ' Type A', ' how  are  you']
['ABC', ' Type B', ' Your  Name?']
['DEF', ' Type A', ' I  am  good']
['DEF', ' Type B', " I'm  Terminator"]
```